# How to pass a message on the following pipeline from background.js to the same extension content script and then to an app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Hey guys I am dealing with a project that needs to communicate with a serial device and unfortunately I can't communicate with the web app directly, so I decide to create an additional extension to see if I can send an information from the packaged app to the extension named as extension "A" and from the extension to the web app.

Right now I have the following chunk of code that is in the packaged app, it only send a simple "hello world", but I do not know what to do in order to send the message from the background.js that is in the extension "A" to the content script and then to the web app

This is the simple dummy test that I did in the packaged extension:

```
var extensionId = "ncccfpjlfecgeggdiigcmakj22223aiiebecd";

var port = chrome.runtime.connect(extensionId);
//send hello world
port.postMessage("hello world");
```

The extension "A" has the following code to recieve the data.

```
var CORE = {
    port: null
};

chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
    CORE.port = port;
    CORE.port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg); // <== message come from the packaged extension.
         /// next lines are where I need to find out how to send this information to the content script and then to the web app.
    });
});
```

The extension "A" has the following informations for the manifest.js

**manifest.js:**

```
{
  "name": "CHANGE THIS : Extension boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
  "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "management",
    "http://*/",
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

content script looks like this.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, respond) {
    console.log("you send hello from brackground to inject");
});
```

Comment: I suggest you read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) (However it fails to mention using `window.postMessage()`, or using custom events). If you have not already done so, you will probably also want to read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview).

Comment: Ok one more question is there any way that at any moment in the background.js of the packaged appp I can pass message back? yes or no? Because I can send a message from the web app to the packaged app and viceversa with the following listener. but is there any other way...?

```chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {  sendResponse("hello im from background.js") }
```